# JDBC Oracle Driver Has Issue With Usernames Containing Special Characters

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Using Vaadin 7 I've created a simple login form that passes the username and password to a class that manages the database connection to an Oracle system. That class then logs in and creates a session.

The following credentials work:

> Username: User1
>
> Password: Password1

These credentials throw errors:

> Username: user1@email.com
>
> Password: Password1

Both are valid users in the database. I've confirmed this by using the above credentials in the Oracle SQL Developer.

My suspicion is that the JDBC driver doesn't like either the '@' or the '.' in the username. Is there a way to escape either character so the JDBC driver ignores it in the connect string?

Stack Trace:

```
Jan 28, 2014 5:07:48 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '
' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:303)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:209)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.<clinit>(OracleDataSource.java:94)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.feith.core.Host.getUserConnection(Host.java:82)
    at com.feith.core.FddSession.<init>(FddSession.java:96)
    at com.feith.userregistration.DatabaseSessionController.DBConnect(DatabaseSessionController.java:123)
    at com.feith.userregistration.DatabaseSessionController.<init>(DatabaseSessionController.java:59)
    at com.feith.userregistration.UserLogin.login(UserLogin.java:158)
    at com.feith.userregistration.UserLogin$1.buttonClick(UserLogin.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:355)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:344)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:523)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:235)
    at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:81)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:230)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:213)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:353)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:396)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:221)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where's the code? Where's the exception stack trace?

Comment: Updated with stack trace. The "com.feith.*" classes are the my classes.

Comment: If with "*confirmed this in Oracle SQL Developer*" you mean that you can connect using that tool, then it's **not** a JDBC issue, because SQL Developer *is* using JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/111070-readme-083278.html), this is a bug (BUG-6362104):
*JDBC driver throws MalformedObjectException or InstanceAlreadyExistsException 
when loading.* . Try to download again the drivers from OTN. If you want to know whether you have the patched jar or not run:

> java -jar ojdbc6.jar

The unpatched jar prints

```
Oracle 11.1.0.6.0-Production JDBC 5.0 complied with JDK1.6
```

and the patched jar prints

```
Oracle 11.1.0.6.0-Production+ JDBC 5.0 complied with JDK1.6
```

Just be sure that you have the latest JDBC driver available for your Oracle DB version.

Comment: There is already an 11.1.0.7 and of course the 11.2.x drivers.